# Questions on dynamical matrix and reduction in number of elastic constants

Tags: solid-state-physics, elasticity

I had two questions involving chapter 22 of Ashcroft and Mermin:

1. On page 438, A&M discuss some symmetries of the real space dynamical matrix. Specifically, I can't see to figure out the argument they are making for symmetry 2,
   $$ D_{\mu  \nu}(\vec{R}-\vec{R}')=D_{\mu  \nu}(\vec{R}'-\vec{R}) $$

Are they trying to say if we completely invert the positions of the atoms in our (monoatomic) crystal, we should expect the same energy? If I go ahead with the replacement they suggest $ \vec{u}(\vec{R}) \rightarrow \vec{-u}(\vec{-R}) $, and insist that the energy of the lattice does not change, I see that the symmetry indeed does follow. Why, though, should we expect the energy not change? This seems intuitively obvious, but only if the potential energy only depends on the magnitude of the displacement between atoms (inversion should not change the distances between the atoms). Is this the case they are describing here, or am I misunderstanding their argument?

2. On page 444, A&M claim that rotating the the crystal should not change its energy. While I certainly agree, I'm having trouble showing that this means we can write $U_{harmonic}$ in terms of the strain tensor. When I plug in $\vec{u}(\vec{R}) = \delta \vec{\omega} \times \vec{R}$ into $U_{harmonic}= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{\vec{R}, \mu, \nu, \sigma, \tau} (\frac{\partial}{\partial x_\sigma} u_\mu (\vec{R})) (\frac{\partial}{\partial x_\tau} u_\nu (\vec{R})) E_{\sigma \mu \tau \nu}$, I get
   $$\sum_{\mu, \nu, \sigma, \tau, i, j} \epsilon_{i \sigma \mu} \epsilon_{j \tau \nu}{\omega}_i{\omega}_j E_{\sigma \mu \tau \nu} = 0$$

I'm not quite sure where to go from here to prove that $U_{harmonic}$ can be written in terms in the strain tensor. Any suggestions?

Thanks for the help!